# QGIS Print Composer Refresh Issue

Tags: qgis

I'm having an issue where QGIS refreshes everything in the composer window before exporting to reflect what is currently in the main display, despite having checked lock layers for map item for each item I've added. So instead of getting a map with three items, one for the continental US, one for Alaska, and one for Hawaii, I get three maps of Hawaii. Is there anything I can do to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I've tried several different things using the lock layers and locking various items etc. It all works for me so you might want to update your QGIS version if you don't have the most recent one. If you do then you could report it to QGIS.

As a work around, if you are trying to create a single composer with multiple pages you might want to swap to have multiple composers, each with a single map.  Or you could have the composer 'controlled by atlas'. You can then use each polygon as a coverage layer, applying a small margin so it all fits nicely on the page. Here's QGIS training on atlas: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

Hope this helps.